# 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем доброго времени суток. Я тут первый раз, не судите строго. У меня бот в телеге, сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой при запуске на сервере, когда запускаю бота локально со своей машины, то работает все как надо. Кто сможет подсказать? Если надо какую-то часть кода отправить, я скину. Спасибо

updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)

2023-11-08 17:26:52,435 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 340, in process_update

handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 122, in handle_update
return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)

File "/root/YAGODKA/my_telegram.py", line 133, in add_users_command
chat_type = update.message.chat.type

AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: Проверьте версии установленного пакета. У вас, скорее всего, разные ветки